# SoundCloud API returns 401 or 403 on some tracks for some client ids

Tags: soundcloud

This sound cloud api call returns 401: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/21402225/stream?client_id=619ab3605c6ce729b96c341a2f6e6ef5`

This sound cloud api call return 403: `api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https://soundcloud.com/blondesound/feel-good-extended&client_id=619ab3605c6ce729b96c341a2f6e6ef5`

Someone said this is due to some permission settings. However, I created a Soundcloud track myself and toggled all permission settings, but I still couldn't reproduce the same error.

I also created another Soundcloud developer account or another Soundcloud app, and tried to access the track above, but I still got the error 401 or 403.

Could someone help me get a successful api call?

Answer (score 1):

Users are able to restrict access to their tracks so that they are not accessible over the api. That is likely what has happened here.

Comment: any plans on changing the behaviour a bit? I see lots of questions about this issue here. Why not give basic track information at all time and only not allow playback etc?